# How do I get data while sending body data using the GET axios method

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

```
const getSchool = async () => {
    const payload = {
        register: "1110000000000",
        id_tingkat_kelas: 11,
        list_id_produk: [
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16
        ]
    };
    
  api.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL_ORIGIN}/mobile/v18/tobk/ujian-sekolah/all`,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-API-KEY": `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}`,
          Authorization: "Bearer " + session?.user?.token,
        },
        data: payload
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      setDataLaporan(res?.data?.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((err) => { });

};
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: ```GET``` methods should not have a body, switch to ```POST``` or other HTTP method

Answer (score 1):

in axios the GET method does not send a body with the request . you usually send the parameters in the url , however you can change the data option to params . so your code will be like this :

```
const getSchool = async () => {
const payload = {
    register: "1110000000000",
    id_tingkat_kelas: 11,
    list_id_produk: [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16
    ]
};

api.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL_ORIGIN}/mobile/v18/tobk/ujian-sekolah/all`,
    {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-API-KEY": `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}`,
            Authorization: "Bearer " + session?.user?.token,
        },
        params: payload 
    }
)
.then((res) => {
    setDataLaporan(res?.data?.data);
    setIsLoading(false);
})
.catch((err) => { });
```

};

you can also switch to another HTTP method like POST to be able to send body in your request

Answer (score 0):

In Axios, the GET method doesn't have a data option in its config object. Instead, you can use the params option to send data in the request body while making a GET request.

```js
const getSchool = async () => {
  const payload = {
    register: "1110000000000",
    id_tingkat_kelas: 11,
    list_id_produk: [
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16
    ]
  };

  try {
    const res = await api.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL_ORIGIN}/mobile/v18/tobk/ujian-sekolah/all`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-API-KEY": `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}`,
        Authorization: "Bearer " + session?.user?.token,
      },
      params: payload // Use params instead of data for GET requests
    });

    setDataLaporan(res?.data?.data);
    setIsLoading(false);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    // Handle error
  }
};
```